# Get max value from row of a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

This is my dataframe df

```
a     b     c
1.2   2    0.1
2.1   1.1  3.2
0.2   1.9  8.8
3.3   7.8  0.12
```

I'm trying to get max value from each row of a dataframe, I m expecting output like this

```
max_value
   2
  3.2
  8.8
  7.8
```

This is what I have tried

```
df[len(df.columns)].argmax()
```

I'm not getting proper output, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Use [`max`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) with `axis=1`:

```
df = df.max(axis=1)
print (df)
0    2.0
1    3.2
2    8.8
3    7.8
dtype: float64
```

And if need new column:

```
df['max_value'] = df.max(axis=1)
print (df)
     a    b     c  max_value
0  1.2  2.0  0.10        2.0
1  2.1  1.1  3.20        3.2
2  0.2  1.9  8.80        8.8
3  3.3  7.8  0.12        7.8
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use `numpy`

```
df.assign(max_value=df.values.max(1))

     a    b     c  max_value
0  1.2  2.0  0.10        2.0
1  2.1  1.1  3.20        3.2
2  0.2  1.9  8.80        8.8
3  3.3  7.8  0.12        7.8
```